# Very basic exercise in Virtual functions

Tags: c#

Alright, so here's the exercise:
You must define three classes. One class named MyNum that contains a variable of type int. Second class called MyString, will be derived from MyNum and contains string. Third-class call MyType and returns a variable of type MyNum. Each class will be set to a constructor function and virtual function called Show. The constructor function of MyType receive a MyNum variable, whereas the function Show of MyType will run the Show function of MyNum.
Now, you need set two objects of type MyType and initialize them. Once an object type MyNum and once an object of type MyString.

Here's the code:

```
class MyNum
{
    protected int num;
    public MyNum(int num)
    {
        this.num = num;
    }
    public virtual void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The number is : " + num);
    }
}
class MyString : MyNum
{
    string str;
    public MyString(string str)
    {
        this.str= str;
    }
}
class MyType : MyNum
{
    MyNum num2;
    public MyType(MyNum num)
    {
        this.num2 = num;
    }
    public override void Show()
    {
        base.Show();
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

I'm having the following error:

Error   1   'ConsoleApplication1.MyNum' does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs  23  16  ConsoleApplication1

Anyone knows why am I having this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your class subclasses `MyNum`, it needs to be able to construct it.  You don't have a default constructor, so you have to explicitly call it with a value.

For example:

```
             // Since this is here, you're saying "MyType is a MyNum"
class MyType : MyNum
{
    MyNum num2;
    public MyType(MyNum num) // You need to call the base class constructor 
                             // here to construct that portion of yourself
       : base(42) // Call this with an int...
    {
        this.num2 = num;
    }
```

The class `MyString` will need similar treatment.  It will have to have a constructor that calls the base class constructor, too.

Note that, if the `MyNum` class had a default constructor (which could be `protected`), this wouldn't matter.  Instead of calling these constructors, the other alternative is to do something like:

```
class MyNum
{
    public MyNum(int num)
    {
        this.num = num;
    }

    // Add a default constructor that gets used by the subclasses:
    protected MyNum()
        : this(42)
    {
    }
```

---

Edit in response to comments:

If you want to override the base class constructor, try:

```
class MyType : MyNum
{
    public MyType(int num)
       : base(num)
    {
    }

    public override void Show()
    {
          Console.WriteLine("The number [MyType] is : " + this.num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Guys , I've edited it I still have this error, on the MyString class and on MyType

Comment: ohh I need to make special constructors for the derived classes?

Comment: @Rich: The derived classes need to call the appropriate constructor of the base class.  Since there is no default constructor (one that takes no arguments), you have to explicitly call the constructor and pass a value.

Comment: public MyNum(string str)
        {
            this.str = str;
        }

Comment: @Rich: Correct.  C# classes don't inherit constructors.  You have to define the constructor on every descendent type.

Comment: @Rich: You need `public MyString(string str) : base(someIntValueHere) { this.str = str; }`

Comment: how am I doing it with MyString?

Comment: @Rich: You don't have to change `MyNum` at all if you don't want to - the error isn't a problem with `MyNum`, it's a problem with trying to subclass it the way you're doing now.

Comment: @Rich: Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx  In particular, search for "base keyword", and look at the section that follows....

Comment: I think I understood it, but why do I need to add an int value right away in the constructor? I want to do it when I'm initializing the objects?

Comment: @Rich: When you subclass an object, you're saying "MyString **is a** MyNum".  However, you've also said that it's impossible to make a "MyNum" without providing a value.  This means, implicitly, that it's impossible to make a MyString without some value - the constructor for MyString has to construct the MyNum "portion of itself" *first* - which requires a number be passed to the base class constructor.

Comment: @Reed: Oh, understood. but, when I declare for example the following:

Comment: @Rich: That's because the `MyType` constructor takes a `MyNum`, not an int.  You need to do:  `MyNum t = new MyType(new MyNum(4));`  [At least, you do with how you have it written now.  If you added a constructor for `MyType` that takes an int, not a MyNum, you could use it ;) ]

Comment: @Reed: Cool! Thanks alot for your time, explaining me, you're a very nice guy.

Comment: @Reed: Oh didn't know it, I'm not getting notifications, anyways.

Comment: @Reed: When I'm doing this: MyNum t = new MyType(new MyNum (4));

Comment: @Reed: It gives me the value of the base value that i implanted earlier in the constructor, instead of "4"

Comment: @Rich: That's because the MyNum you pass in is stored in num2 - it doesn't override the base class value (that would be `this.num`)

Comment: @Reed: Oh I understand, I thought it will override it, so what's the solution for that?

Comment: @Rich: Edited my answer to demo

Answer (score 2):

MyString implicitely has a zero-arg constructor because you did not specify any constructor in that class. You could either declare a zero-arg constructor in the super class or declare a one-arg constructor in MyString.

Comment: The problem is with `MyNum`, not `MyString`

Comment: He also needs to handle this in `MyType`, since the constructor parameters are of a different type...

Comment: Guys , I've edited it I still have this error, on the MyString class and on MyType

Comment: @Ken: No, the problem is that `MyString` and `MyType` subclass `MyNum`, but do it inappropriately. The error message refers to `MyNum`, but `MyNum` is fine as it stands.

Comment: @Reed: Sorry. What I meant to mention was that, by default, a child class's constructor calls the parameterless parent class's constructor. Either way, the correct answer should mention the implicit constructor chaining, since this is the other half to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

MyString does not have a constructor, so it will use the one from the base class MyNum, which doesn't have a default one with no parameters.

MyString needs a constructor or you need a paramterless one in the base class.

Comment: Guys , I've edited it I still have this error, on the MyString class and on MyType

Comment: He also needs to handle this in `MyType`, since the constructor parameters are of a different type...